# series_fir not generating moving average on application insights chart

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

Given the following [Kusto query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/series-firfunction):

```
range t from bin(now(), 1h)-23h to bin(now(), 1h) step 1h
| summarize t=make_list(t)
| project id='TS', val=dynamic([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,20,40,100,40,20,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]), t
| extend 5h_MovingAvg=series_fir(val, dynamic([1,1,1,1,1])),
     5h_MovingAvg_centered=series_fir(val, dynamic([1,1,1,1,1]), true, true)
| render timechart
```

I am unable to get application insights to actually draw the moving average lines shown in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/series-firfunction)

I have also tried applying the article to one of our actual applications and have not had any luck either. There are no errors or anything that would give a clue as to why the moving averages are not being drawn. I'm assuming there is a setting somewhere that most probably has to be set. Here is my custom query:

```
let timeGrain=1d;
let ago = ago(7d);
let mAvgParm = repeat(1, 5);
let dataset=requests
// additional filters can be applied here
| where timestamp >= ago and cloud_RoleName == "recalculateordercombination" and resultCode == 500
| where client_Type != "Browser" ;
// calculate failed request count for all requests
dataset
| make-series dailyFailure=sum(itemCount) default=0 on timestamp in range(ago, now(), timeGrain) by resultCode
// render result in a chart
| extend SMA = series_fir(dailyFailure, mAvgParm)
| render timechart
```

**What are these queries missing in order to draw the moving average lines using `series_fir`?**

*ref articles used in my research*

- https://marckean.com/2019/03/25/log-analytics-advanced-queries/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/series-firfunction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web clients for both services are different, and that's also true for their rendering logic.

In Azure Data Explorer (Kusto), you can just use `render timechart` on time-series data (which is typed as `dynamic`).

In other cases, you may need to first `mv-expand` the series ([link to doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator)), before rendering it.

Here's an example which matches the first query in your question:

```
range t from bin(now(), 1h)-23h to bin(now(), 1h) step 1h
| summarize t=make_list(t)
| project id='TS', val=dynamic([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,20,40,100,40,20,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]), t
| extend 5h_MovingAvg=series_fir(val, dynamic([1,1,1,1,1])),
     5h_MovingAvg_centered=series_fir(val, dynamic([1,1,1,1,1]), true, true)
| mv-expand val to typeof(long), t to typeof(datetime), 5h_MovingAvg to typeof(long), 5h_MovingAvg_centered to typeof(long)
| project t, 5h_MovingAvg, 5h_MovingAvg_centered, val
| render timechart
```